# Battleship: place ships

Tags: c

I wrote a battleship game on AVR device. Everything works just fine, only placing ships on game map causes little problems. Sometimes ships are placed next to each others even if I thought my code would prevent that. Have tried to debug it now for two days. Thought to just place the code of the place_ships -function here if someone of you could notice where I'm wrong with it.

```
int data_map[10][10]; //This has the data of where ships are, where player has shot etc.
char game_map[10][10]; //This is printed in UI. O for miss, X for hit.

int ship_sizes[] = {0,1,2,3,3,4,5};
int ships[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

void place_ships() {                        //Places the ships in the game map.

int other_ships;                        //Variabel for counting if there are already other ships in the area where trying place the ship.

for (i=6; i>0; i--) {

    while (1) {
        other_ships = 0;                //Initialize.
        ship_direction = rand() % 10;   //Get random ship direction (1-4 = horizontal, 6-10 = vertical)
        top_x = (rand() % 8) + 1;       //Get random x-coordinate, not from map edges
        top_y = (rand() % 8) + 1;       //Get random y-coordinate, not from map edges

        if (ship_direction < 5) {       

            if ((top_x-ship_sizes[i]) > -2) {       //Make sure that ship has room in game map.

                for (j=(top_y-1); j<(top_y+2); j++) {       //Following 2 for-loops and if-statement inside makes sure that no other ships are in
                                                            //the area where the ship is tried to place.
                    for (k=(top_x+1); k>(top_x-(ship_sizes[i]-2)); k--) {

                        if ((data_map[j][k] == 1) || (data_map[j][k] == 2) || (data_map[j][k] == 3) || (data_map[j][k] == 4) || (data_map[j][k] == 5) || (data_map[j][k] == 6)) {
                            other_ships = 1;        //Following 2 'breaks' and 'continue' are there for the situation if
                            break;                  //there are other ships in the area, stop placing ship and get new random coordinate and try again.
                        }
                    }

                if (other_ships == 1) {

                        break;
                }

                }

                if (other_ships == 1) {

                        continue;
                    }

                for (l=top_x; l>(top_x-ship_sizes[i]); l--) {

                    data_map[top_y][l] = ships[i];      //If no other ships in the area, place the ship.

                }

                loading();                              //Wait to optimize harware working. There are known timing issues on AVR. And this
                                                        //is here to try to avoid them.
                break;
            }
        }

        else if (ship_direction > 5) {

            if ((top_y-ship_sizes[i]) > -2) { //Make sure that ship has room in game map.

                for (j=(top_y+1); j>(top_y-(ship_sizes[i]-2)); j--) {   //Following 2 for-loops and if-statement inside makes sure that no other ships are in
                                                                        //the area where the ship is tryied toplace.
                    for (k=(top_x-1); k<(top_x+2); k++) {

                        if ((data_map[j][k] == 1) || (data_map[j][k] == 2) || (data_map[j][k] == 3) || (data_map[j][k] == 4) || (data_map[j][k] == 5) || (data_map[j][k] == 6)) {

                            other_ships = 1;        //Following 2 'breaks' and 'continue' are there for the situation if
                            break;                  //there are other ships in the area, stop placing ship and get new random coordinate and try again.
                        }
                    }

                if (other_ships == 1) {

                        break;
                }

                }

                if (other_ships == 1) {

                        continue;
                    }

                for (l=top_y; l>((top_y-(ship_sizes[i]))); l--) {

                    data_map[l][top_x] = ships[i];      //If no other ships in the area, place the ship.

                }

                loading();                              //Wait to optimize harware working. There are known timing issues on AVR. And this
                                                        //is here to try to avoid them.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now the original problem is solved. Still some ships aren't placed. What ships function skips, varies.

Comment: What does `ships` contain?

Comment: int ships[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

Comment: Did you find any errors?

Comment: Why there is two '3's in the array ship_sizes[]??? Is that what it meant to be??

Comment: Yes. I have 6 ships: ship 1(size 1), ship 2(size 2), ship 3(size 3), ship 4(size 3), ship 5(size 4) and ship 6(size5). What were you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last variant:

```
for (k=(top_x+1); k>(top_x-(ship_sizes[i]-2)); k--) {
```

I think the condition should be:

```
k > ( top_x - (ship_sizes[i] + 2) )  // not -2 but + 2
```

because as I suppose you want to check that the ship will not overlap all the length of the ship_sizes[i] and adjacent ones. The same is for y:

```
top_y-(ship_sizes[i] + 2)  // or top_y - ship_sizes[i] - 2
```

I recommend you to extract this code to the function, such as CheckOverlap, because it will simplify the code reading and debugging.

Also, move up the valuation of the condition from the loop:

```
int length = top_x - (ship_sizes[i] + 2);
for (k= top_x+1; k > length; k--) {
```

Clearer code will also be:

```
int IsPlaced (j,k) {
    return 1 <= data_map[j][k] && data_map[j][k] <=6;
}
```

In general, **try to avoid code duplication**, placing all doubling to functions. It will reduce the doubling errors and strongly simplify the design of your program, what is good for you and for all other readers.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! Now the conditions should be right. Still not every ship is placed on the game field. The code is skipping to place one or two of the ships. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: How this could be the case as you'll run in the loop until you find the place for the ship?  `while (1)`

Comment: That is just what I'm just now wondering. It may be that I have not assigned the delays of the AVR board properly in this function. I've learned that the board coul do really crazy things if delays are not right or if there is some errors in code.

Comment: But i wanted to ask about the function "IsPlaced". Could you explain in words what the function should be doing? Which arguments it should take and what is the value it is returning? Where shoud I call that function in place_ships?

Comment: but it's just written... Instead of checking 
 `if ((data_map[j][k] == 1) || (data_map[j][k] == 2) || (data_map[j][k] == 3) || (data_map[j][k] == 4) || (data_map[j][k] == 5) || (data_map[j][k] == 6)) {`
You can call this function. Or just simplify the condition.
Also it is nothing bad in going out of nested loops with goto, it is better than checking the flag other_ships each time.

Comment: Oh, okey! Wise advices, thanks. I appreciate. This is just second coding project from me. The first was minesweeper on python so i'm stil a genuine newbie. I'll be correcting and simplifying those things you mentioned and after that try to look if they have some influences of the program working.

Comment: [Avoid code duplication](http://www.slideshare.net/kindblad/avoid-code-duplication-principles-patterns) - this is very simple technique and very powerful at the same time. Just this one design principle will strongly improve your code quality.

Comment: Have not thought about that so much. Will definitely improve my coding thanks to this. Appreciate!

Comment: Where would you assign the "goto"-statment to go in this code?

Comment: I think I got the right code. It is somehow just the AVR board itself which is messing up the place ships -process.

Answer (score 1):

The tests you're doing on `data_map` to find other ships are reading past the end of the array.  You should clean up those loop conditions.  For example, `top_x` can be as high as 8 after being assigned `(rand() % 8) + 1`.  Then `ship_sizes[i]` can be as high as 5.  So `top_x+(ship_sizes[i]+2)` can be 15.

I'm not sure fixing that will solve your problem, though, but it's a problem of its own.

You will find that the problem is in array indexing.  Arrays in C are 0-indexed, and in several places you treat them as if they're 1-indexed.

Comment: You're RIGHT! I fixed the code to be like this.. ash, i'll edit the original post

Comment: That makes sense.  It seems you were placing the ships starting backwards at `top_x` or `top_y`, but you were searching for other ships starting forward at `top_x` or `top_y`.

Comment: That's right! Still the code i edited in original post did not fix the ships getting next to each other/overlapping.

Comment: I think that somehow the loops before checking for the other ships aren't executed properly. The code never gets to "other_ships =1" even if there are other ships.

Comment: Now you've got `for (j=(top_y+1); j<(top_y-(ship_sizes[i]-2)); j--)`, which should be `j >`, right?

Comment: Right! :D -> rebuild -> test -> let u know if works!

Comment: Great! Now it works. Still some problems though. For some reason not every six ships are placed. So the function skips to place some ships. The ships what the function is skipping are varying. I tested like for 4-5 games and sometimes even the first ship (ship number 6) is skipped to place. I can't get what could be causing this. Do you?

Comment: I would print some debugging information to see if the ships aren't being placed or if they're being placed off-board or being overwritten.  You should easily be able to add a `printf` with the `data_map` indices and values within the loop where you're doing the actual placement.